# get the earliest date from several tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables with timestamp columns. I was wanted to write a query to find out which was the earliest data point (ignoring any null values). This is the query i have at the moment:

```
SELECT gps.time,
       cadence.added_on,
       `heart-rate`.added_on
FROM   gps
       JOIN cadence
         ON cadence.rider_id = gps.rider_id
       JOIN `heart-rate`
         ON `heart-rate`.rider_id = gps.rider_id
ORDER  BY gps.time,
          cadence.added_on,
          `heart-rate`.added_on;
```

how do i return just the earliest date? My SQL is pretty basic, and i would like to learn more about the language.

Thanks for your help

Comment: The earliest data point per rider or just in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`least`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least) for the earliest date per row and if you want the earliest date
overall you can order by `least`.

```
SELECT least(gps.time,
       cadence.added_on,
       `heart-rate`.added_on)
FROM   gps
       JOIN cadence
         ON cadence.rider_id = gps.rider_id
       JOIN `heart-rate`
         ON `heart-rate`.rider_id = gps.rider_id
ORDER  BY least(gps.time,
          cadence.added_on,
          `heart-rate`.added_on)
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another variant would be using subqueries:

```
SELECT least(
    (SELECT min(time) FROM gps),
    (SELECT min(added_on) FROM cadence),
    (SELECT min(added_on) FROM `heart-rate`)
) AS oldest;
```

Or to get the newest entry and not the oldest:

```
SELECT greatest(
    (SELECT max(time) FROM gps),
    (SELECT max(added_on) FROM cadence),
    (SELECT max(added_on) FROM `heart-rate`)
) AS newest;
```